# MAMP--I don't know what the web URL should be when setting up a testing server in Dreamweaver

Tags: mamp

I use Dreamweaver and I have a file (PhpTest.php) that I placed in the htdocs folder within the MAMP folder. I've assigned the testing server a name and I've specified a connection type (local/network) and appropriate server folder (a folder that doubles as the PhpTest.php Dreamweaver site folder). Now it's asking me to assign a website URL and I'm at a total loss. I've tried

```
http://localhost/PhpTest/
```

as well as the URL of the MAMP ready-page, but nothing's working (I use Chrome, and if it's not already apparent I'm only just now learning PHP).

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If PhpTest.php is in htdocs you should try:

```
http://localhost:8888/PhpTest.php
```

Have you started mamp? (You should start the server by double clicking on the mamp app icon)
To check that 8888 is the correct port you can click on the faq tab in the mamp launch web page .

Comment: PhpTest.php is in a folder within htdocs called PhpTest. I tried your suggestion and it seems like the server is connected! I'm no longer getting an error that the server could not be found, but now I'm getting a 404 not found stating "The requested URL /PhpTest.php/PhpTest.php was not found on this server." If you have any idea how to fix that I'd be really grateful, but either way I think you've fixed my initial problem, thanks!!

Comment: Works like a charm! Much obliged.